# how to redirect all links from old domain to same links but in domain?

Tags: .htaccess

how to redirect all links from old domain to same links but in domain ?
it's my website , how can I redirect (htaccess ) all my old links to new links , 
for example :

```
http://stroi-rf.ru/index.php?route=product/category&path=18_110
http://snab-rf.ru/index.php?route=product/category&path=18_110
```

I want to change just stroi-rf.ru by snab-rf.ru in all my link's .
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [rewrite 301 replace domain name with a new domain name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680974/rewrite-301-replace-domain-name-with-a-new-domain-name)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Redirect 301 / http://snab-rf.ru
```

in the htaccess file in the `stroi-rf.ru`'s document root.

Comment: I don't have access to stroi-rf.ru ,

Comment: I can just add code in snab-rf.ru not to stroi-rf.ru . can you show me other way ?

Comment: @user2841405 if you don't have access to the site you want *to redirect **from**,* then there's nothing you can do